# How to initiate the call to a PHP function when I submit a form

Tags: php, function

I want to call on my functions in my user class once I have submitted my form, so far I have the below:

```
if(isset($_POST)){
$run = new Users();}
$run->preventaccess();

if(isset($_POST['registerForm'])) {
$run->validate();
$run->insert();
}


if(isset($_POST['loginForm'])) {
$run->login($username, $password);
$run->validatelogin();}
```

However this hasn't worked at all, it takes me to my class page but the page is left blank and the query is not executed?

Any ideas how I can get this to work?

```
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="POST" action="classes/class.Users.php">
        <h1><span class="log-in">Log in</span> or <span class="sign-up"><a href="register">sign up</a></span></h1>
        <div id="errorDiv"></div>
    <p class="float">
        <label for="login"><i class="icon-user"></i>Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
          <span class="errorFeedback errorSpan" id="emailError">Username is required</span>
    </p>
    <p class="float">
        <label for="password"><i class="icon-lock"></i>Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="showpassword"> 
                <span class="errorFeedback errorSpan" id="passwordError">Password is required</span>

    </p>
    <p class="clearfix"> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log in"></form>
    </p>
```

Comment: Try closing the form after the <p> tag. Also, close your inputs tags like this <input .... />

Comment: Does the form actually have a value in `$_POST`. I'd have to check, but I don't think `<form name="loginForm"` would actually have a value, so `if(isset($_POST['loginForm']))` is always false.

Comment: @EdsonHorácioJunior this didn't work

Comment: @gutigrewal add value="" to your inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

```
    if(isset($_POST)){
$run = new Users();}
$run->preventaccess();

if(isset($_POST['registerForm'])) {
$run->validate();
$run->insert();
}


if(isset($_POST['usethisvalue'])) {
$run->login($username, $password);
$run->validatelogin();}
```

---

```
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="POST" action="classes/class.Users.php">
        <h1><span class="log-in">Log in</span> or <span class="sign-up"><a href="register">sign up</a></span></h1>
        <div id="errorDiv"></div>
    <p class="float">
        <label for="login"><i class="icon-user"></i>Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
          <span class="errorFeedback errorSpan" id="emailError">Username is required</span>
    </p>
    <p class="float">
        <label for="password"><i class="icon-lock"></i>Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="showpassword"> 
                <span class="errorFeedback errorSpan" id="passwordError">Password is required</span>

    </p>
    <p class="clearfix"> 
        <input type="submit" name="usethisvalue" value="Log in"></form>
    </p>
```

> you should not use form name in your post method,instead assign name
>   in your submit as shown and check it in your post method.

Answer (score 0):

Try including the functions script in your document??!

```
<?php include_once("../path/to/functions.php"); ?>

HTML goes here?
```

Am I missing something really obvious here? You have to make your functions available to the page somehow.

Comment: That doesn't work, I am making my functions available the way I am doing this now is by calling my functions in the user class after the end of the close. My functions work fine when  I call them normally however I don't want them to be activated until I have posted my form.

Comment: Why not? They won't exactly activate or take up space. Perhaps have a class that you can extend? I'm not really a PHP dev, but in ColdFusion, I would create a component (class) and then extend this with my other components. After that, I can then call the methods from within my class using the super keyword, like, super.myMethod()